# How can I base the file name off of an already existing variable?

Tags: bash, grep, io-redirection, variable

I'm using this to delete lines that don't match a pattern:

```
$ egrep "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5"
```

But now I need to do it automatically, so I'm setting a variable like this:

```
$ catTMP=~/mpp/*.xml
```

And I want to run something like this:

```
$ egrep "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5" $catTMP > $catTMP.2
^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^_^__^Here^
```

How would I base the redirect name off of what variable already exists? If you still don't understand, I mean something like this:

```
$ cd ~/mpp/
$ ls
x.xml 

$ egrep "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5" $catTMP > $catTMP.2

$ ls
x.xml x.xml.2
```

Or even better would be in place editing, but `grep` can't do that, so maybe there is a way to do this with another command, and just do something like `-i`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit in place, keeping only lines that match the pattern:

```
sed -n -r -i "/(pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5)/p" ~/mpp/*.xml
```

On BSD `sed` (Mac OSX), try:

```
sed -n -E -i '' "/(pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5)/p" ~/mpp/*.xml
```

#### Basing the file name off of an already existing variable

```
for fname in ~/mpp/*.xml
do
    egrep "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5" "$fname" > "$fname.2"
done
```

The above works because a period is not legal in a variable name.  Consequently, the shell knows that, in `$fname.2`, the variable name is just `fname`.  If that is not case, then curly braces are required.  For example:

```
for fname in ~/mpp/*.xml
do
    egrep "pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5" "$fname" > "${fname}_2"
done
```

Here, the curly braces make clear to the shell that the variable name is `fname`, not `fname_2`.

Comment: Im using BSD sed, just checking before if it works on BSD sed?

Comment: @DisplayName Thanks for the update.  There are two possible issues.  One is that `-r` should be replaced with `-E`.  The other is that some versions of sed require that an argument be given for `-i`.

Comment: Yeah, i usually use `-i ''`

Comment: @DisplayName If this answer solved your problem, please consider marking it Accepted so that others browsing the site know that this question has been answered.

Comment: Yeah i usually do that. It did solve my question, but since it doesn't answer what the title says I'm not sure if the people looking for how to do this will be happy with the answer.

Comment: @DisplayName OK.  I have added a section to answer the question in the title.

Comment: Ok, accepted :).

Answer (score 0):

using `awk`

```
for x in `ls ~/map/*.xml`;do awk '/(pattern1|pattern2|pattern3|pattern4|pattern5)/{print}' $x > $x.2; done
```

the for will loop over all xml file and awk find pattern , if matched will store in .xml.2

Answer (score 0):

You can use `grep` like:

```
for f in /dir/*glob*
do  grep -E 'pattern|list' <<INFILE >"$f"
$(cat "$f")
INFILE
done
```

It will drop any trailing blank lines from each file in `$f` but my assumption was that blank lines were probably not among your `pattern|list` anyway.